# Google Fusion Tables: Several issues (appearance of deleted markers, caching issues..)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

This is what I'm trying to do. Create 3 Fusion Tables layers and then have them toggled by checkboxes above the map.

I've already implemented that functionality but I've run into issues where some old (deleted) locations are appearing on the map. I'm trying with a custom refreshLayerX() and refreshLayerY() functions but to no avail.

At the beginning, I had my 2 layers shown initially (the 3rd layer will be added after I have this working). But after making additions, only one layer is shown (and that's the one that is showing old locations).

I'm suspecting this might be caused by caching but I'm not 100% sure that reload/refresh functions don't work as expected.

Also, on this website I've found a question about the same (or at least very similar) issue and the suggested way to solve it was to add this (and this was taken from the Google Groups, and provided by a Google person):

```
$("img[src*='googleapis']").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("src",$(this).attr("src")+"&"+(new Date()).getTime());
});
```

The problem is I don't know how to add this in plain javascript.

Any help will be appreaciated!

EDIT: Here's a screenshot of how I see the map when I visit the page http://screencast.com/t/DVqtGs7rR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has this problem, it's probably best to delete the layer and start over. Google seem to have cache of its own which you can't refresh. You should be good if you have your data in a Google spreadsheet so that you can easily import it into a new layer. Make sure first that the file (spreadsheet) is made Public, otherwise you won't be able to import! Upon importing, of course, don't forget to update the table ID!